# How to know the cache line of A8 chip is 64 bytes?

Tags: ios, processor

How the get the information of the apple chip cache line .aka ,the A8 cache line ?I have google it for a long time ,but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it here? http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/I998929.html. There's a pre-existing question that asks about it. All I had to do was Google "apple a8 cache line".
[What is the cache line size on iPhone and iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132821/what-is-the-cache-line-size-on-iphone-and-ipad)